# Generate an HTML file using vb.net

Tags: html, css, vb.net

I have created a program that merges files and I have decided to output the results as an HTML document so that it is legible. I have achieved this output using System.IO.StreamWriter and creating a textfile with all the html formatting and in-line CSS and saving it with the .html extension like so:

```
Dim lstrBackupOutput = "Test.html"
Dim lobjWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(lstrBackupOutput)
Dim lobjWriter as 
lobjWriter.WriteLine("<html>")
lobjWriter.WriteLine("</head>")
lobjWriter.WriteLine("<style type=""text/css""> h1,h2,h3{font-family:Arial, Serif;}  table{border-collapse:collapse; width:100%; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;} th{height:30px;} td{text-align:left; padding:7px;} table, th, td{border:1px solid green;} </style>")
lobjWriter.WriteLine("</head>")
```

etc.

Is there more of a VB.NET way to do this? Most of my searches churn out ASP.NET results that don't seem to apply.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want an legible output have you considered XML and XLST?

Comment: Also, can you describe what you mean by "my searches churn out ASP.NET results that don't seem to apply"?

Comment: Well when I tried to reference htmltextwriter it didn't seem to find the reference in system. So I assumed it was just an asp thing =/

Comment: I'll take a look at XML/XLST, it seems to be a popular answer :). thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use XSLT for this approach 9 times out of 10.

It depends on how much dynamic data you need to have in the HTML. If it's a good amount, or you need repeating rows of data, then XSLT is the way to go.

Here's a good start if you are unfamiliar with XSLT: [XSLT Tutorial (W3Schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp')

Answer (score 1):

check out this article http://cdmckay.org/blog/2009/02/01/creating-an-html-document-with-net/

The XML approach is a good start...

```
' Create the body element and append it to the root.
Dim xmlBody As XmlElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("body")
xmlRoot.AppendChild(xmlBody)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use [HtmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx#Y7000).

Comment: So based on the quote below from MSDN I take it HtmlTextWriter only works for ASP.net applications. It isn't snowing up at all for my Windows forms app

[HtmlTextWriter] - "Writes markup characters and text to an ASP.NET server control output stream. This class provides formatting capabilities that ASP.NET server controls use when rendering markup to clients."